# Cant get event.target.value using select item from material-ui autocomplete with onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, textfield

*** CODE UPDATED FROM SUGGESTIONS ****** 
I am learning to use material-ui. I cant find many examples of combining it with event handling. I have used an autocomplete and a textfield to create a suggested list of data fetched from an API. I can render the selected list but on clicking one of the selections I can't get the value clicked on to be passed to a member function of the react class. Do I need to bind the event properly to the autocomplete? How should I do this. Line 25 in my code logs the event target to the console but it is always 0 ( null I assume ) . How can I set the value of the this.state.data to the clicked option ?

I tried adding      autoSelect={true}

I also tried moving this line of code into the textarea .
onChange={this.updateState}

```
import React from "react"
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

class App extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            itemSelected: false,
            inputVal: ''}

            this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this)

        };

        updateState(e) {
            e.persist()
            const newValue = e.target.value
            this.setState({inputVal: newValue, itemSelected: true});
            console.log(e.target.value);

            // eventually I want to render a DIV with data from the selected value
        }

        /// fetch some data

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            /* .then(json => console.log(json)) */

            .then(data => this.setState({data, isLoaded: true}));
    }

    render() {

        const {isLoaded, itemSelected} = this.state;




        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div> loading ...</div>;
        } else if (itemSelected) {
            return <div> item selected </div>
        } else {
            const limo = this.state.data;
            return (
                <div>

                    <Autocomplete
                        freeSolo
                        disableClearable
                        autoSelect={true}
                        id = "limoSelect"
                        onChange={this.updateState}
                        value = {this.state.inputVal}
                        options={limo.map(option => "body: '" + option.body + '\n' + "'      id: " + option.id)}
                        renderInput={params => (

                            <TextField
                                {...params}
                                label="Type In Content"
                                id="limoText"
                                value = ''
                                autoSelect={true}
                                margin="normal"
                                variant="outlined"
                                fullWidth
                                InputProps={{...params.InputProps, type: 'search'}}

                            />


                        )}
                    />
                </div>
            );

        }
    }
}

App.defaultProps = {}

export default App;
```

console logs zero . 
When you click on the option the updateState is called and this variable is being set
this.state.itemSelected = true; 
No error messages .
I am hoping the console.log in the updateState can be made to log the clicked item !

Comment: try using e.persist() before fetching value

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. I tried this code but still logging zero :      updateState(e) {
            e.persist()
            this.setState({inputVal: e.target.value, itemSelected: true});
            console.log(e.target.value);

            // eventually I want to render a DIV with data from the selected value
        }

Comment: I also tried storing the value at the top of the function to try and deal with what might be an asynchronous issue  : const newValue = e.target.value . That didn't help either.

Comment: I think I've found a solution, check my answer's edit

Comment: Thanks !! That's a great help Nicolas. I am still trying to dig into that event and get the id of the clicked on option. I tried logging console.log(e.target) : I wonder how I can access the value of the "data-option-index" . If I could pull that id out I could render what I need which is all the info from the json data.  <li tabindex="-1" role="option" id="limoSelect-option-4" data-option-index="4" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" class="MuiAutocomplete-option" data-focus="true">body: 'repudiandae veniam quaerat

Comment: @SeanWayland You can get it using ```console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data-option-index"))```. If it solved your issue, please accept my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: Using `e.target.textContent` will do the trick. 
Here is a live [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mclean-qzi4h) to check the code (modified some parts, applying the tips below and some other things).

---

Don't mutate state manually like this:

```
this.state.itemSelected = true
```

Use setState (like you're already doing for other state items):

```
 updateState(e) {
    this.setState({ inputVal: e.target.value, itemSelected: true });
    console.log(e.target.value);
    // eventually I want to render a DIV with data from the selected value
  }
```

Also a tip, you can use array destructuring:

```
const {isLoaded, itemSelected} = this.state;
```

Instead of

```
var isloaded = this.state.isLoaded;
var itemSelected = this.state.itemSelected;
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas those are good suggestions. Using your updateState method the console.log(e.target.value) produces a zero. The clicked on option is not being passed up to that function I think.

Comment: the const suggestion created this error . "Line 49:14:  'isloaded' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: The error is because you had "var isloaded" and state is "isLoaded". Change ```isloaded``` to ```IsLoaded``` here ```if (!isloaded)```

Answer (score 3):

onChange signature: function(event: object, value: any) => void

Here's an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default class Tags extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tags: []
    };
    this.onTagsChange = this.onTagsChange.bind(this);
  }

  onTagsChange = (event, values) => {
    this.setState({
      tags: values
    }, () => {
      // This will output an array of objects
      // given by Autocompelte options property.
      console.log(this.state.tags);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: 500 }}>
        <Autocomplete
          multiple
          options={top100Films}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
          defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
          onChange={this.onTagsChange}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              variant="standard"
              label="Multiple values"
              placeholder="Favorites"
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', year: 2003 },
  { title: 'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly', year: 1966 },
  { title: 'Fight Club', year: 1999 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', year: 2001 },
  { title: 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back', year: 1980 },
  { title: 'Forrest Gump', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'Inception', year: 2010 },
];
```